# What is the best method to generate a sinusoidal-appearing interpolation with maximums and minimums at the points you're interpolating between?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, cubic-spline

I have a series of values and times in an array. I want to create a spline fit wherein the derivative at every point that I give it is at zero. In short, I want to form a complex sinusoidal-looking wave from it. Each value should end up being either a local minimum or a local maximum. in the output. When I interpolate with the `interp1` 'spline' function, the first derivative at each given point is not zero. In reference to the code below, `slopes1` should ideally equal to zero for `t = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`. I hope that this makes sense. 
If this is not possible with splines, then what would be the best approach to generate an oscillating curve with a series of minimums and maximums that are continuously 1st and 2nd order differentiable?

```
t=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y=[1,-2,2,-1,6,-5,1,-1,8,-5];
pp = interp1(t,y,'spline','pp');
slopes1=ppval(pp_der,t);
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53517842/8239061

Comment: Not much to do here, right? If you want third order passing through p0 and p1 with slope 0 at both, this already defines all 4 parameters of a 3rd order function.

Comment: You could look into a `pchip' interpolation. I don't think the derivatives at your points will necessarily be zero, but it should perform better than a spline as it does not enforce anything for the second derivatives.