# interpolate to decrease step size Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-analysis

I have data arrays in matlab like this: 1 , 2 , 3 ; 2 , 4 , 6 ; ... is there a ready to use algorithm in Matlab which can interpolate data and give me something like this (for linear e.g) 1 , 2 , 3; 1.5 , 3 , 4.5; 2 , 4 , 6;

in this example my steps are going to 0.5 instead of 1.
this is the easy case for linear interpolation. imagine i have 10000 rows and i want have cubic interpolation and increase the resolution between my data.... I know there is mathematics algorithms but first I want to make sure if there is any ready to use function for that.

Comment: Googling for “MATLAB interpolate” gives lots of solutions, with relevant MATLAB documentation at the top. Please put a bit of effort into searching before you ask. And when you ask, show your efforts and why those don’t solve your problem. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want Matlab's `interp1` function.

```
% Data points to interpolate
v = [1 2 3
     2 4 6
     ];
% X (independent variable) points for the original data
x = [1:size(v,1)]';
% X points to do the interpolation at
xq = [1:0.5:size(v,1)]';
% Do the interpolation
v_interp = interp1(x, v, xq);
```

The fourth argument to `interp1()` is an option that specifies what interpolation method to use, and takes arguments like `'linear'`, `'cubic'`, `'spline'`, and so forth. See `doc interpn` for details.

Decrease the step size in `xq = [1:0.5:size(v,1)]'` to increase the resolution.

Comment: Thanks..thats exactly what I was looking for

Comment: `interp1` will do this without a loop.

Comment: Thanks beaker! I've updated my answer to use interp1 and avoid the for loop.

Comment: Just be careful what method you use.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524024/8239061) for example of what can go wrong.