# How do I create a vectorized version of randsample in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, vectorization, distribution

I have a support (`supp_epsilon`) and a probability mass function (`pr_mass_epsilon`) in Matlab, constructed as follows.

```
    supp_epsilon=[0.005 0.01;
                  0.01  0.015;
                  0.015 0.02;
                  0.02  0.025]; 

    suppsize_epsilon=size(supp_epsilon,1);

    pr_mass_epsilon=zeros(suppsize_epsilon,1);

    mu_epsilon=[0; 0];
    sigma_epsilon=[1 0.5; 0.5 1];
    
    pr_mass_epsilon=zeros(suppsize_epsilon,1);

    for j=1:suppsize_epsilon
 pr_mass_epsilon(j)=mvnpdf(supp_epsilon(j,:),mu_epsilon.',sigma_epsilon)/sum(mvnpdf(supp_epsilon,mu_epsilon.',sigma_epsilon));
     end
```

Note: `supp_epsilon` is `4x2`. Each `1x2` row of `supp_epsilon` is an element of the support of interest.

**Question:** I want to draw `n=10` **vectors** of size `1x2` from `pr_mass_epsilon`. Each of these vectors has to be a row of `supp_epsilon`. For `n` very large the empirical frequency of the drawn vectors has to be close to `pr_mass_epsilon`.

How can I do this?

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58607156/8239061) addresses the scalar case where the answer suggests to use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html).

Comment: just use `randsample(whatever_it_is,2)`

Comment: It gives me error: `epsilon=randsample(supp_epsilon, n, true, pr_mass_epsilon,2)`;

Comment: `Error using randsample (line 74)
POPULATION must be a vector.`

Comment: You say you want `n` random vectors. What is `n`,  and why is `supp_epsilon` a matrix and not a vector?

Comment: Thanks. `supp_epsilon` is now a matrix because it represents the support of a bivariate random vector. Each `1x2` row of `supp_epsilon` is a possible realisation of such bivariate random vector. `pr_mass_epsilon` is the associated probability mass function.

Comment: Is this a use-case for [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)?

Comment: Is your bi-variate (or univariate) support discrete or continuous?  Your use of the term probability mass function suggests **discrete**; invoking [`mvnpdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html) suggests **continuous**.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan The support is discrete and equal to `supp_epsilon`. I construct the probability mass function by truncating and discretising a multivariate normal, but this is just one example.

Comment: @user3285148 Ok, thanks. So `sum(pr_mass_epsilon) = 1` and it is indeed a PMF, not a PDF.  The idea is to develop this for any given `pr_mass_epsilon`, is that right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.